# Best way to override java.util.logging Level class to change the level strings

Tags: java, java.util.logging

My aim is to use the java.util.logging Level class and change the Level strings like 'FINE' to 'VERBOSE'.

`public static final Level FINE = new Level("FINE", 500);`

I know we can do this by extending the Level as follows:

```
public class MyLogLevel extends Level {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8176160795706313070L;
    private static final Level FINE = new MyLogLevel("VERBOSE", 500);

    protected MyLogLevel(String name, int level) {
        super(name, level);
    }


}
```

I would like to know, is this the good way to do it or are there any better ways to do it.

Comment: Seems pretty good. Do you have a problem on an error?

Comment: Wouldn't the problem be that any library code that directly uses `Level.FINE` would not be replaced? Why do you want to replace those strings in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Oracle JDK or OpenJDK you can simply override the localized names of the existing levels.  You do this by creating new resource bundle (properties file or resource bundle class) under the package `sun.util.logging.resources`.  The [bundle name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-java.lang.ClassLoader-) must be in the form of `logging_LANG_COUNTRY`.

For example, here is a test program under project called `LevelTest`:

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;

public class NewLevels {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
        ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("sun.util.logging.resources.logging");
        System.out.println(rb.getLocale());
        System.out.println(Level.FINE.getLocalizedName());
        System.out.println(Level.FINER.getLocalizedName());
        System.out.println(Level.FINEST.getLocalizedName());
    }
}
```

When I execute this test the locale printed is `en_US`.  Therefore my resource bundle name will be `logging_en_US.properties`.

The properties resource bundle will contain the following:

```
FINE=VERBOSE
FINER=VERBOSE
FINEST=VERBOSE
```

Here is a listing of the project structure:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Projects\LevelTest\src\NewLevels.java
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Projects\LevelTest\src\sun\util\logging\resources\logging_en_US.properties
```

When I run the program I get the following output:

```
en_US
en_US
VERBOSE
VERBOSE
VERBOSE
```

On a larger project, you might have to fight some of the class loader issues to ensure that the correct resource bundle is located.

Alternatively, if you don't want to do that you can resort to creating a [custom formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Formatter.html).