# How to customize the default java logging?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I need to have custom log levels(other than java.util.logging.Level), and custom functions in the java util logger to log messages of these levels.

Custom levels:
1. DEBUG
2. ERROR
3. FATAL

So I created XYZLevel extended from Level as follows:

```
public class OKILevel extends Level {

public OKILevel(String name, int value) {
    super(name, value);
}

/* OKI Log Levels */
public static final Level FATAL = new OKILevel("FATAL",
        Level.SEVERE.intValue() + 100);

public static final Level ERROR = new OKILevel("ERROR",
        Level.SEVERE.intValue());

public static final Level DEBUG = new OKILevel("DEBUG",
        Level.FINE.intValue());

}
```

Custom functions required:
.debug(), .severe() etc similar to .info in logger.

For logger I do:

```
static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ABC.class.getName());
```

I am unable to figure out:

```
static final XYZLogger logger = XYZLogger.getLogger(ABC.class.getName());
```

extending the Logger doesn't help.

Also, for this application the logging.properties need to be passed in.
How do I use these new levels in .level of logging.properties?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating log wrapper then you should leverage some of the standard frameworks before inventing something new.

If you want your application to use a new logger implementation then you have to implement and install a custom [LogManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html).

> Also, for this application the logging.properties need to be passed in. How do I use these new levels in .level of logging.properties?

All of the `.level` parsing performed via the
[`Level.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html#parse-java.lang.String-) method.  Per the docs:

> The argument string may consist of either a level name or an integer value.
>
> For example:
>
> - "SEVERE"
> - "1000"

So you should be able to write:

```
#Level.SEVERE + 100 = FATAL
some.logger.name.level = 1100
```

That said there are some known issues with [finding the correct level value by int](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187073) in some releases of Java.

Another option if you just want the rendered output of a level to be different then you should have a look at [Best way to override java.util.logging Level class to change the level strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44827573/best-way-to-override-java-util-logging-level-class-to-change-the-level-strings).